# Rtsp streaming using VideoView and MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I wana to develop android app that will play rtsp link from local server, but the tablet screen goes blank.... showing nothing
    I had tried both `VideoView` and `MediaPlayer` classes.
Work well on youtube rtsp links with .3gp extension but not working on the above URL
    Below is my code

```
public class WifiManagerActivity extends Activity {

private WifiManager  customWifiManager;
private VideoView mu;
private String path;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wifiSettings();
    }

    private void wifiSettings() {
        mu  = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.ttl);
        TextView notify = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_state);
        customWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if(customWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your wifi is On now enjoy " +
                    "live streaming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notify.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            showVideo();
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Turn your Wifi On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        customWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        //two second wait here
        showVideo();
        }

    }

    private void showVideo() {


        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticater());
        String path = "rtsp://192.168.1.155:554/3g";
        mu.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        mu.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mu.requestFocus();
        mu.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange ............ no one give me suggestion till now

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors that can affect whether your stream is playing correctly or not:

1. check whether your stream is valid and playable (using for example separate instance of VLC)
2. if that works check logcat for any errors/warnings related to either RTSP connection or video stream itself. Look for tags like: *MediaPlayer*, *ARTSPConnection*, *MyHandler*, *ASessionDescription*, *ACodec*.

That should get you started.